# android - Latency hiccup with setting imageView content

Tags: bitmap, imageview, drawable

I already searched and found a lot on this topic, but none of the answers helped me.

My program is a drumcomputer, actually it's working fine, execpt for this latency bug.

The visual architecture is the following:
A HorizontalScrollView contains a LinearLayout (LayoutRhythm, vertical).
This Layout contains one Linearlayout for each Track.
The TrackLayout (horizontal) contains multiple ImageViews for each sound.

Just for the Imagination:
HorizontalScrollView
rhythmLayout
trackLayout ImageView ImageView ImageView ... ImageView ImageView trackLayout
trackLayout ImageView ImageView ImageView ... ImageView ImageView trackLayout
trackLayout ImageView ImageView ImageView ... ImageView ImageView trackLayout
/rhythmLayout
/HorizontalScrollView

The first location is the buildRhythm function, where I have to check the rhythm, and the set the corresponging png-image (which is just around 665 bytes!) to all imageViews.
The second Location is the OnClick Listener of the ImageView, which changes the image of itself.

In my buildRhythm method I call the follwoing method to get an ImageView:

```
private ImageView getRhythmImage(int playerTrackindex, int playerSoundIndex, int soundIndexViews, int zoomLevel){

    final ImageView sound = new ImageView(this);
    final int trackIndexViews=playerTrackindex+1;
    final int trackIndexPlayer = playerTrackindex;
    final int soundIndexPlayer=playerSoundIndex;

    if (soundIndexViews % zoomLevel == 0) {
    //sound.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.strich);
    sound.setBackgroundDrawable(drawableStrich);
    }
    else {
    //sound.setBackgroundResource(0);
    sound.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    }

    if(this.awesomePlayer.actualRhythm.tracks.get(playerTrackindex).sounds.get(playerSoundIndex).equals("1")){
         //sound.setImageResource(R.drawable.bob);
         sound.setImageBitmap(bitmapBob);
    }
    else{
        sound.setImageBitmap(bitmapnobob);
    }
    //sound.setImageDrawable(getRhythmDrawable(playerTrackindex, playerSoundIndex));
    //sound.setImageResource(getRhythmImageId(playerTrackindex, playerSoundIndex));
    sound.setId(playerSoundIndex);

    sound.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            awesomePlayer.changeRhythmElement(trackIndexPlayer, soundIndexPlayer);
            if(awesomePlayer.actualRhythm.tracks.get(trackIndexViews-1).sounds.get(soundIndexPlayer).equals("1")){

                sound.setImageBitmap(bitmapBob);
                //sound.setImageDrawable(drawableBob);
                //sound.setImageResource(R.drawable.bop);
                sound.invalidate();
            }
            else {
                sound.setImageBitmap(bitmapnobob);
                //sound.setImageDrawable(drawablenobob);
                //sound.setImageResource(R.drawable.nobop);
                sound.invalidate();
            }
        }
    });
    System.gc();
    return sound;
}
```

You see, at first I used sound.setImageResource(R.drawable.bop) for setting the ImageView Content. 
In the android doc (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) I found out, that this method decodes the resource in the UI thread and that it can cause latency

"Awesome" I thought :)
"I got the solution"

So I changed everything to drawables and most important:
I set the drawables in my OnCreate method, so that they already exist and just have to be connected to the imageViews. But nothing changed.
Then I changed everything into bitmap using

```
this.bitmapBob = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bop);
this.bitmapnobob = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nobop);
```

in my OnCreate method. But nothing changed.
I have multiple track with around 100-200 ImageViews in each, but I'm too new in android to know why it's lagging.
The latency to change an image of an ImageView is about 2-3 seconds.

Am I using Bitmap the wrong way?
Are the tons of ImageViews the problem?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that Android doesn't really like putting multiple image views on the screen at the same (more or less) time. Especially when you're trying to make it work for 200 of them.

To solve your problem, please tell me why did you choose to use multiple imageViews over drawing just one?

I know this is kinda late answer, hope you've already solved it. If so, please share your solution.

Comment: Hey there, thank your for your answer. I choose multiple ImageView, because I have to implement an OnClickListener to each of it. The program is a drumcomputer and every ImageView symbolizes a single note/tone, like a single basedrumkick. To change the tone, the user kann click on it and the image of it will change to the "note exist"-/"note does not exist"-Image. And no, :( I did not solve the problem. I read about using horizontal List Views and I got to try that...

Comment: Could you upload your code somewhere? I'll see what I can do for you.

Comment: I could, but at the moment, this project is paused :) But I wanna try out the implementation of ListViews. I just have to change the structure, but ListViews should solve the problem, cause they seem to unload everything thats not on the screen. Thx for your help :)